# Mysql can't start?

Tags: mysql-5.5

Mysql can't start, here is the log :

```
150708 06:28:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150708  6:28:36 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150708  6:28:36 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43) starting as process 13122 ...
150708  6:28:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150708  6:28:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150708  6:28:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150708  6:28:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150708  6:28:36 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150708  6:28:36 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150708  6:28:36 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150708  6:28:36 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
150708  6:28:36  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
150708  6:28:36  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140002885236704 in file fsp0fsp.c line 2102
InnoDB: Failing assertion: inode
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
04:28:36 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
```

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

```
key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=400
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
```

It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1266177 K  bytes of memory.

Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

```
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x78ca9e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x493)[0x675553]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf710)[0x7f54f5fc8710]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f54f440e625]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7f54f440fe05]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8a2f20]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8a2fb2]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8af255]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x87fc41]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x8309ba]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x7fc490]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x41)[0x6781a1]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x58e048]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x928)[0x591c38]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x518568]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x3fd)[0x51b72d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f54f43fad5d]
/usr/libexec/mysqld[0x511335]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
150708 06:28:36 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: What are these varibles set to in your my.cnf?

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=N
innodb_buffer_pool_size=NNN

Answer (score 3):

*(!!! Make a backup first before trying the following !!!)*

Step 1 : Setting in your ini file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

(*Change your mysql port from 3306 to something else if you don't want clients to reconnect during your recovery*)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Step 2: Increase the number carefully until you have your database to start-up at least again.

Step 3: Try to figure out which table is corrupted:

```
mysqlcheck --port (newport) --all-databases
```

Step 4: Then dump your data/structure to recreate the corrupted table:

```
mysqldump my_database table > database.table.sql
```

Or ... if possible (not too much data), dump the whole database and recreate all.

Step 5: Restart your database, or a new/clean database in normal mode, and import your recovered data.

(*when all is fixed, use the standard port again*)